# Please fix the big gap in the line height of the new Off-Topic reason list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, off-topic

For some reason the choices listed under the Off-Topic list are all bunched toegther which makes reading difficult and creates a big empty gap between the last reason and the Vote to Close button.

> [image]

**Proposed fix**: By increasing the text of each reason's line-height (e.g. `line-height:20px`), it's not only easier on the eyes, but fits the space better too.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is intentional to be able to add other off-topic close reasons in the future.

Comment: @HamZa - Maybe. But in the future they can change the style to something else. For now my eyes would appreciate the change.

Comment: Are there any examples of other sites that use the whole space? If the CSS is shared across the network, it would have to accommodate the sites which use more close reasons than SO does.

Comment: Is it perhaps to allow room for the "other" comment box when it's shown?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName - That's another thing that confuses me. Why does the comment box for "other" show up when you click the radio button for that reason, but it doesn't disappear if you then pick another reason?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins or not necessarily more reasons, but wordier ones. :-)

Comment: I'm completing this, because as far as I can tell, this  is now much better on all sites. I just can't find the dup of this that got marked as completed.

Comment: @TimPost - Hmmm, aside from the close reasons changing since I posted this, the actual styling doesn't look like it was changed. There's still a big gap at the bottom and the lines are still too close together.

Comment: @TimPost - I still don't see this as completed on SO, which is what originated my post. Can you remove the status-completed tag?